# Type mismatch when trying to replace

Tags: stata

I have a variable age_n .  it is numeric (float).
for exampel if i type 
    count if age_n>65
If gives me 77.

So then if I type 
    replace age_n = "0" if (age_n < "65")
it says type mismatch.
I have tried putting 65 without quotes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: may be because `"0"` - its character? `replace age_n = 0 if (age_n < 65)` not work?

Answer (score 1):

Another form to do it is

```
recode age_n (0/65=0 "0") (66/150=1 "over 65")
```

So you have a dummy with your requirement (from 0 to 65, values change to 0, appearing a "0" in the table; from 66 to 150, values change to 1, appearing this time "over 65" in the table). If you want to maintain values of `age_n`,

```
gen age_n2=age_n
```

and do the process with `age_n2` instead of `age_n`.